# Selecting all rows from two tables

Tags: mysql

I've been trying to select everything from two tables at the same time.

Unfortunately, I didn't create the database and I can't just merge it into one table.

I tried this, but it doesn't work:
`(SELECT * FROM 'contacts') UNION (SELECT * FROM 'signup')`

Both tables are the same. This doesn't work though :(

Comment: Why doesn't it work?  Does it give an error saying you are not selecting the same number of fields in both queries?

Comment: Show us the tables structure to see what you might be missing. Don't forget to add the column datatypes.

Comment: Never `SELECT *` in a `UNION` query. Be explicit about the order of the columns in each `SELECT` list, even if you believe them to be the same.

Comment: (actually, never `SELECT *` anywhere in production code)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't you just do:

```
SELECT * FROM contacts, signup;
```

Or am I not understanding your question?

EDIT:

Try this instead if you're looking for a UNION:

```
SELECT * FROM contacts
UNION
SELECT * FROM signup;
```

Comment: No, that is a different output. This results in a cartesian product - all rows of `contacts` multiplied by all rows of `signup`.

Comment: Use DISTINCT if you don't want duplicates

Comment: @Neurofluxation Don't use this, as it isn't the right way to concatenate two tables. Even if you add `DISTINCT` to dedup the rows, this is a join query, not the union you're apparently looking for.

Comment: DISTINCT makes the query retrieve no results?

Comment: @Neurofluxation Doesn't return duplicates read [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp)

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is incorrect.  Tables should not be quoted by apostrophes.  They *can* (but don't have to be) quoted by backticks.

```
SELECT columns FROM contacts UNION SELECT columns FROM signup
```

Replace `columns` with the columns you want to select.  Also note that this will select *all* of the `contacts` rows first followed by the `signup` rows.